# ¿Cómo puedo determinar el ganador de una ronda de torneo en PHP7?

Tags: json, formularios, php7

Estoy haciendo una web en **php7** sobre torneos de cartas. He conseguido hacer los emparejamientos, pero no sé como anotar quién gana, o quién empata. **El método de para llevar las puntuciones es suizo**. He pensado en crear formularios dependiendo de cada ronda, y escribir las puntuaciones en un **JSON** que guarda la información de cada jugador.
El JSON sería una cosa parecida a esto:

```
{
  "torneo": {
    "participante": [
      {
        "nombre": "Rafa",
        "puntostorneo": "4"
      },
      {
        "nombre": "Jorge",
        "puntostorneo": "3"
      }
    ],
    "ronda": {
      "numero": "3",
      "ganan": "Rafa",
      "empatan": "Jorge, Inda"
    }
  }
}
```

Y el código tal y como lo tengo actualmente es este:
**EDITO**: He actualizado el código y ahora sí obtengo los ganadores de cada ronda, ya sólo queda pasarlos al json.

```
 <!-- Muy importante asigarle un ID a cada formulario, para evittar problemas -->
    <form id="formboton" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <?php
        //Nos aseguramos de que la cantidad de rondas sea un número entero
        if (isset($_POST['cantrondas']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && is_numeric($_POST['cantrondas'])) {
            $cantrondas = (int) $_POST['cantrondas'];
            $nombres = $_POST['nombre'];

            //Nos aseguramos de que se cumpla el mínimo de participantes y el numero max y min de rondas
            $numparticipantes = count($nombres);
            if ($numparticipantes < 4) {
                    echo "Debes seleccionar cuatro o más participantes";
                    }
                else {
                    echo "Se van a jugar $cantrondas rondas, con $numparticipantes participantes </br>";
                    //Procedemos a emparejar a los usuarios, si son pares o no
                    if ($numparticipantes % 2 == 0) {
                        echo "EMPAREJAMIENTOS RONDA 1:</br>";
                        //Añadimos el emparejamiento de la primera ronda
                        shuffle($nombres); //Mezclamos los nombres
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($nombres) ; $i+=2) { //El operador += establece el valor de $i como si se hubiera dicho $i = $i+2;
                            echo $nombres[$i]." vs ".$nombres[$i+1]."<br>";
                    }                  
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "EMPAREJAMIENTOS RONDA 1: Selecciona al ganador, o los jugadores que empatan</br>";
                        $bye = "BYE";
                        //Añadimos el bye, al array para indicar que el que se quede solo tenga la victoria automática
                        array_push($nombres, $bye);
                        shuffle($nombres);
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($nombres) ; $i+=2) {
                            $nombreizda = $nombres[$i];
                            $nombredcha = $nombres[$i+1];
                             echo $nombres[$i]." <input type='checkbox' name='gana[]' value='$nombreizda'>"." vs ".$nombres[$i+1]." <input type='checkbox' name='gana[]' value='$nombredcha'>"." Empate <input type='checkbox' name='empate[]' value='Empate'>"."<br>";
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            echo"Debes introducir todos los datos";
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> &nbsp; <input type="reset" value="Reestablecer">
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['gana'])) {
            $ganadores = $_POST['gana'];
            echo"<br>";
            echo"Ganan la primera ronda: ".implode(", ", $ganadores);
        }
        else {
            die("Cuando envíes la lista de participantes, selecciona quién gana o empata");
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo regular las competencias son eliminatorias; por consiguiente los que llegan a la final uno obtiene el triunfo (el que gano).

Para tu planteamiento te sugiero la siguiente estructura para tu **Json** (al final la consideración):

```
{

   "torneo" : 
        {
            "nombre" : "Nombre del torneo",  /* Este opcional por si quieres usar el nombre del torneo */
            "participantes": 
                [
                    {
                        "idPersona": 0, /* Este seria incrementarlos por cada uno */
                        "nombre": "Rafa"
                    },
                    {
                        "idPersona": 1,
                        "nombre": "Jorge"
                    },
                    {
                        "idPersona": N, /* El "n" participante */
                        "nombre": "Participante N"
                    }
                ]
            "rondas": 
                [
                    { /* Primero Ronda */ 
                        "idRonda" : 1, /* Primer ronda */
                        "contendientes":
                            [
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : 1, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                },
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : 2, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                },
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : N, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                }
                            ]
                    },
                    { /* Segunda Ronda */ 
                        "idRonda" : 2, /* Psegunda ronda */
                        "contendientes":
                            [
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : 1, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                },
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : 2, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                },
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : N, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                }
                            ]
                    },
                    { /* Ronda N */ 
                        "idRonda" : N, /* Ronda N */
                        "contendientes":
                            [
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : 1, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                },
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : 2, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                },
                                {
                                    "idContienda" : N, /* Esto seria numero de mesa o simple identificador */
                                    "idContendientes" : /* quienes fueron los contendiente */
                                        ["idPersona", "idPersona"], /* Los idPersna de cada contrincante */
                                    "ganador" : "idPersona" /* IdPersona que gano, en caso empate sea cero */
                                }
                            ]
                    }

                ]

        }

}
```

Consideración:

- Si el ganador es quien más triunfos obtuvo será buscar conforme a cada *`idPersona`* (en *`participantes`*) quien esta como *`ganador`* (en cada *`rondas[0..N].contendientes[0..M].ganador`*)

si con lo anterior más de uno coinciden en más ganados, deberás solicitar de que formas en orden de prioridad se resolveran los desempates.

Comment: Lo tendendré en cuenta, gracias

Comment: El problema es generarlo de forma automática desde php7

Comment: Otra duda, por qué el id persona debe ser un número y no directamente el nombre?

Comment: Otra aclaración: El sistema de emparejamientos es suizo

Comment: **Generarlo automáticamente** R= En lo que compartste no vi origen de los datos; el proceso a realizar depende como este para con iteracciones generar la estructura. **idPersona numero** R= Lo propongo por si existe más de un "Rafa", "Jorge",..., en caso nombre únicos puedes usar nombre. **Emparejamiento suizo** R= Esa parte debe ser implementada por código, la estructura lleva registro de gano, perdio y empato, el método de desempate que corresponda debe ser elaborado por separado.

Comment: El código completo está aquí:https://github.com/RafaelAybar/Mantis-rebirth/blob/master/creartorneo.php